# Merge property values with Sass

Tags: sass, less

When I use Less, I can merge some of css properties via [merge feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature):

Less:

```
.mixin() {
  box-shadow+: inset 0 0 10px #555;
}
.myclass {
  .mixin();
  box-shadow+: 0 0 20px black;
}
```

To css:

```
.myclass {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #555, 0 0 20px black;
}
```

Is there any way to do that with Sass?

Answer (score -1):

You could use `@extend` (http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7) to merge properties or (which I would recommend) use a CSS minifier to do so.
clean-css (https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) or cssnano (http://cssnano.co/) do a really good job.